# google-cloud-datastore not working inside a flask app in a docker container

Tags: docker, flask, google-cloud-datastore

I have a flask server inside a docker container. If I add the import statement `form google.cloud import datastore` in the beginning, the server starts hanging and does not respond. In a local miniconda environment the flask server starts properly with the import statement. Anyone with an idea what causes this different behavior?

Comment: It is possible that this package requires authentication. In your local environment (file system) you have it, inside docker you do not.

Comment: google-auth is part of the miniconda environment and the variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set properly. The import works well in a container, which does not have a flask server.